# Alexa App not following 302 redirects issued by ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: android, ios, alexa-skills-kit, asp.net-core-identity

I'm working on an Alexa skill that supports account linking and am hosting the infrastructure for linking accounts using ASP.NET Core with ASP.NET Core Identity in a Microsoft Azure AppService website in IIS.

I've implemented the ability to sign-in using Amazon, Facebook, GitHub, Google, Microsoft and Twitter via the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.*` NuGet packages. These all work perfectly fine for standard sign-in in a web browser, and also for manual testing of the account linking process through a browser.

When using the iOS Alexa App however, only Amazon and Facebook are working. Google isn't working because its use from embedded apps is disallowed (I get a Google 403 page telling me this), but for the other three I have no idea what's going on to stop things working. Things work fine in iOS Safari, so it appears to be nothing global to the iPhone or iPad where I've tested it to work OK.

GitHub, Microsoft and Twitter all appear to hang when the sign-in form is submitted.

I use a CSP, so I thought that maybe the `form-action` list was not correct (for example, sometimes Amazon redirected to `na.account.amazon.com` which caused it fail at first as I thought only `account.amazon.com` would be used), but the problems persisted when the CSP list was updated to temporarily allow anything to rule out the CSP. Also, I use `report-uri.io` with the CSP, which has received no errors.

I've run my iPhone and iPad through Fiddler as a proxy, and found that the embedded page correctly submits the HTTP POST to my site, which responds in all 6 cases with the correct HTTP 302 response. In the case of Amazon and Facebook, the 302 is followed and things work as expected. For the remaining three with the issue, that appears to be the end of the requests from the Alexa App.

It seems that the embedded browser is completely ignoring the HTTP 302s, leaving the user in limbo while trying to sign in.

I've also tried the Android Alexa App, which exhibits different behaviour:

1. Amazon - redirect loads Chrome, breaking the in-app flow;
2. Facebook - works correctly;
3. GitHub - redirect loads Chrome, breaking the in-app flow;
4. Google - works correctly;
5. Microsoft - redirect loads Chrome, breaking the in-app flow;
6. Twitter - redirect loads Chrome, breaking the in-app flow.

The only common denominator is that Facebook and Google work for both apps (though Google disallow its use on iOS).

What could I be doing/missing that could be causing the Alexa Apps to not be following these redirects correctly? What would cause the iOS app to not follow the redirects? What would cause the Android app to open the redirects in Chrome instead of in the in-app browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the Alexa app appears to (seemingly at random) decide to follow, or not, redirection URLs during the account linking process.

If you list the possible hosts that are used during account linking in the optional list of Authorization URLs in the skill configuration in the developer portal, things will work as expected.

Determined after finding this comment on the Amazon developer forum: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/answers/27564/view.html